# Which MongoDB framework is best to use with java and spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to the MongoDb will any one please tell me that which framework is best to use with java and spring. Also please suggest me the links to refer that how to design DB and relation between document.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this project which is a very good spring and mongodb integration tool

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/

Comment: Thank you for help. But will you please suggest me other than spring-data-mongodb